# How to consume or access Azure AD exposed API(MyApis)?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

I have my confidential client and resource client registered in AAD.
The confidential client has API permissions to access the resource client.
After I logged in from the confidential client with my credentials how can I can make a request to the resource client?

**Based on the [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis)**

**For example, if your web API's application ID URI is https://contoso.com/api and your scope name is Employees.Read.All, the full scope is:
https://contoso.com/api/Employees.Read.All**

The example is not enough for me to understand like where's the access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain the access token.

First, get `code` by the url in your browser. You need to login in this step.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={your-client-id}
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://contoso.com/api/Employees.Read.All
&state=12345
```

Then, get access_token with the code.

```
POST  https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id={your-client-id}
&scope=https://contoso.com/api/Employees.Read.All
&code={the code from the previous step}
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret={your-client-secret}
```

[image]

---

About implicit grant flow:

This flow is usually used for single-page apps, and the implicit grant presents more risks than other grants. Please check if the implicit grant is suitable for your app, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#is-the-implicit-grant-suitable-for-my-app). If not, I still recommend you use auth code flow.

**Note:** To let it work, you need to select access tokens under the Implicit grant section in the portal first, navigate to App registrations -> your application -> Authentication.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={your-client-id}
&response_type=token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&scope=https://contoso.com/api/Employees.Read.All
&response_mode=fragment
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
&prompt=none
```

Comment: Is that client credentials flow? Can't I get an access token using Microsoft login page?

Comment: No, it is just auth code flow. client credentials flow is used for application, not for user.

Comment: @RonaldAbellano "get an access token using Microsoft login page". Do you mean that call the URL with browser, and then get access_token directly?

Comment: Yes. So the user is a tenant member in my AAD. I have registered a confidential client where the user can login. And I have a resource application API that is exposed. From the client I will consume the resource application api.
Is it possible or it is not?

Comment: As my answer shows, you need to login in by the first URL to get the code. Then obtain the access token with this code. If you want to login in and get access token in just one step,  you can just use 
[Implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#getting-access-tokens-silently-in-the-background). I will add it in my reply.